# TypeError: (intermediate value).apply is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit a form with the button that is not inside the form...

```
<form id="updateForm">
<input type="text" name="a" />
<input type="text" name="b" />
</form>

<input type="button" class="done"/>
```

I have this jquery function that I tried

```
$(".done").click('#updateForm','submit',function(e)
{

    $.ajax(
    {

    });
});
```

But... I get the error. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: That is invalid syntax, jQuery's `click()` doesn't take any of those arguments, and it's unclear why you added them, and what you're trying to do?

Comment: Well... When I click on input that has class done it should submit the form with an id updateForm

Comment: That was my main objective

Comment: @NiranjanKumar TypeError: (intermediate value).apply is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to submit the form, that's what you should do

```
$(".done").click(function() {

    var form = $('#updateForm');

    $.ajax({
        url  : form.prop('action'),
        type : form.prop('method'),
        data : form.serialize()
    }).done(function(result) {

    });
});
```

Comment: Well... I do not want page to redirect. I tried this method too... I should have preventDefault(); somewhere!

Comment: @Alexis - then you'd use ajax

Comment: Works! Thank you :)